# How to set Cronjob in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, cron

i have a problem with my cronjob.

```
* * * * * /var/www/html/AutoUpdate.php
```

why is my cronjob not working? not updating everyminute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The job is not running because you have not specified the program that should run .php files . Just change it to include the location of php e.g.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/AutoUpdate.php
```

And you should be through.

Comment: If the script has a valid shebang you don't need to put the interpreter on the command line. But the question is too broad, too vague, and almost certainly a duplicate.

Comment: :) glad that I could help